# Download a pdf from binary variable in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

In the database, I have a blob column where I save a pdf. Through a query I store in a string the contents of the blob column, in binary format.

To download the pdf from string variable "doc.file" I use:

```
a.secondary-content.btn-floating.btn-large.waves-effect.waves-light.blue.darken-4.tooltipped(data-position='left' data-tooltip='Download' href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent( doc.file ) download='EstrattoConto'+doc.data+'.pdf')
                                    i.material-icons(style='font-size: 40px;')
                                        | file_download
```

I use pug and nodejs and for this I have some limitations, such as the use of the DOM (use jQuery instead) due to PUG and the BLOB variable due to NODEJS.

The file open but is white and empty.

Downloading directly from the db with workbench the file works correctly, I think it is a conversion problem, also because opening the files in a text editor there are these differences:

**Working**:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (þÿ)
/Creator (þÿ)
/Producer (þÿ Q t   5 . 5 . 1)
/CreationDate (D:20200217153210)
>>
```

**White**:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (��)
/Creator (��)
/Producer (�� Q t   5 . 5 . 1)
/CreationDate (D:20200217152834)
>>
```

Comment: It looks like you may have a text encoding issue. Can you verify that you're actually getting UTF-8 output out of your DB? You didn't mention what DB you're using, but if memory serves well, I believe the default charset in mySQL is Latin1.

Comment: yes, is latin1 (or binary, is the same), if i save directly from db with workbench and rename in .pdf work perfectly. i want to know how  set  href for do the same from the download button.